# How to create a docker base image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, suse

My local system is ubuntu 14.04. In this local system, I installed VM which contains sles 12. In this local VM (sles 12), I configure some of the application of my use.

I'm totally new to Docker. I want to create a docker base image which contains this sles 12 image into which my applications are also present.

How I can create such a docker image, in which sles 12 os is available and into that my applications also can be run?

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages) have a section on creating base images.

The `FROM` will still be required but you can use the reserved "scratch" name here to create a base image from scratch (nice naming there Docker)

```
FROM scratch
ADD hello /
CMD ["/hello"]
```

Taken from the section on [creating a base image using scratch](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/#/creating-a-simple-base-image-using-scratch)

Comment: @mickadoo- I don't want to create base image from scratch. I want to create a base image of existing virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a base SLES image. Luckily for you, this process is [semi]automated by SUSE through the utility called sle2docker. A manual can be found here:
https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles-12/book_sles_docker/data/cha_sle2docker_installation.html
https://github.com/SUSE/sle2docker

Then you should run your container, install and setup your custom software and do `docker commit` to create you personal customized image. 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockerimages/

Comment: Can you explain me in more detail so that I can understand better.